# Displaying Digits Beginning from 0.000000001 to 0.999999999 in C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to print out the numbers mentioned in the title with a loop with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ceiling = 1;
float counter = 0;
int main()
{
while (counter < ceiling)
{
    printf("%f\n", counter);
    counter = counter + 0.000000001;
}
}
```

but it only gives me 7 digits of precision. Is there any way to get 10 digits of precision?

Comment: Use a double instead of float.

Comment: Hey wafflesausage, I just had a look at your profile and saw your 9 questions with answers, none of which were accepted.  You might want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have to paste this again... [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

I'll have to make a browser plugin for this task!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get that precision out of a `float`.  Even with `double` you may end up with rounding errors during the count that could appear to skip or repeat some numbers.  In a pinch, you can use `double` with 9 decimal places like this:

```
printf( "%.9f\n", counter );
```

But consider using an `int` instead.  This will handle all 9-digit numbers you need.  And you just print them with zero-padding:

```
int counter = 0;
int ceiling = 1000000000;
while( counter < ceiling ) {
    printf( "0.%09d\n", counter );
    counter++;
}
```

The above will of course print trailing zeros.  It's not clear whether you want that or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. How exactly does printf( "0.%09d\n", counter ); work?

Comment: `%09d` formats an integer to 9 digits with zero-padding.  `0.` is just text - pretending it's a decimal number.  By the way, I should have mentioned that `int` is not guaranteed to be large enough.  The standard only says it's at least 16-bits (even though it's commonly 32-bits these days).  You need at least 32-bits, so I should probably have suggested `long`.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to switch it to long to be safe.

Comment: Feel free to try it with `double`.  Unless you're a very fast reader, you might want to make another program to check that the output doesn't stutter over its 1 billion lines of output.